# How can I avoid adding all routes to the app object in NodeJS with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

In my NodeJS application using Express it seems like I need to add all my "get" paths to the "app" express variable. It would be nice if I only had to register the module and not register each route. I'm coming from an ASP.NET MVC background where if I make a Controller class then it gets automatically routed to. Is there a way to make Express work like this or do I need to add the routes to this one ever growing file of paths? Can it do some sort of reflection or is there a way to set this up?

```
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

import stylus = require('stylus');
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express 4 you can mount Routers (like miniature Express apps) on a base path, so you could set up a Router to handle all `/user/*` paths, one for `/article/*` paths, etc.:

```
app.use('/user', routers.user);
app.use('/article', routers.article);
// ...
```

You can then put the logic for these routers in separate files and just require and use them in wherever it makes sense (e.g. in your main `app.js` or even inside another router).

See [this Express 4 docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) for more details.